# Property is not flushed

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

I call a service in a controller:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('pro_convocation')->sendDelegationEmails();
```

Here it is the method executed with the service:

```
function sendDelegationEmails()
{
    foreach ($this->getRepository()->findWithPendingDelegationsEmail(1) as $convocation) {
        if (! $convocation->delegationsEmailCanBeSent()) continue;
        $this->sendDelegationsEmails($convocation);
        $convocation->_setDelegationsEmailIsSent();  //<--- it is not saved
        $this->save($convocation);
    }
}
```

and the other used methods in the same class:

```
/**
 * @return \Pro\ConvocationBundle\Entity\ConvocationRepository
 */
private function getRepository()
{
    return $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ProConvocationBundle:Convocation');
}

function save(ConvocationEntity $convocation)
{
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($convocation);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}

function sendDefinitiveMinute(ConvocationEntity $convocation)
{
    foreach ($convocation->getCommunity()->getMembers() as $user) {
        $this->get('pro.notifications')->send(Notification::create()
            ...
            ->setBody($this->get('templating')->render(
                'ProConvocationBundle:Convocation:definitive-minute.html.twig',
                array(
                    'convocation' => $convocation,
                    'convocationIsOrdinary' => $this->get('pro_convocation.ordinariness')->isOrdinary($convocation),
                    'user' => $user
                )
            ))
        );
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** The `send` method:

```
function send(Notification $notification)
{
    if (! $notification->getRecipient()) throw new \Exception("Recipient not set");

    if (! $notification->getRecipient()->getEmail()) {
        $this->logger->info(sprintf(
            "Notification \"%s\" ignored as recipient %s has no email",
            $notification->getSubject(), $notification->getRecipient()));

        return;
    }

    // Ignore notifications to the own author
    if ($notification->getAuthor() === $notification->getRecipient()) {
        $this->logger->info(sprintf(
            "Notification ignored as recipient is the author (%s)",
            $notification->getRecipient()));

        return;
    }

    $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
    $em->persist($notification);
    $em->flush();

    if ($this->notificationHasToBeMailed($notification)) {
        $this->mail($notification);
        $this->logger->info("Notification mailed to {$notification->getRecipient()}");
    }
}
```

**END EDIT**

The `_setDelegationsEmailIsSent` method and `delegationsEmailIsSent` property in the `Convocation` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="delegations_email_is_sent")
 * @Constraints\NotNull
 */
private $delegationsEmailIsSent = false;


/**
 * @internal
 * @see \Pro\ConvocationBundle\Convocation::sendDelegationsEmails()
 */
function _setDelegationsEmailIsSent()
{
    $this->delegationsEmailIsSent = true;
}
```

The problem is that `delegations_email_is_sent` in the database is not changing to true when executing the `sendDelegationEmails` method in a controller. I've tried several changes without success. It seems to be related to `flush` method, but I don't find the issue.

Comment: You are certain that _setDelegationsEmailIsSent is being called?

Comment: @Cerad - `$this->sendDelegationsEmails($convocation);` is called, so I think it is called.

Comment: Stick a die statement in there just to verify.  Otherwise, multiple entity manager's are the only thing I can think of.  Your 'pro_convocation' services gets the entire container injected?

Comment: @Cerad - I'm executing it from the console with a command. So `exit` won't help. But there are multiple entity managers. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Cerad - You may now find the issue.

Comment: @Cerad - And yes, the `pro_convocation` service is getting: `arguments: [@service_container]`

Comment: die works fine in the console.  All I can suggest is to try and inject the specific entity manager instead of getting it from the doctrine object.  It seems like you are somehow switching managers?  Does not seem very likely.